# Swift: Simplify menu button logic

Tags: ios, swift, switch-statement

I have a game in Swift where each of my levels is a separate class inherited from the base GameScene class (it's a lot easier this way for what I'm doing, don't judge me).
I also have a menu which has a button for each level. This is how the buttons loads the level:

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
  if let t = touches.first {
    let node = atPoint(t.location(in: self))
    if let name = node.name {
      let newScene: GameScene!
      switch Int(name)! {
      case 1:
        newScene = Level1(size: frame.size)
      case 2:
        newScene = Level2(size: frame.size)
      case 3:
        newScene = Level3(size: frame.size)
      case 4:
        newScene = Level4(size: frame.size)
      case 5:
        newScene = Level5(size: frame.size)
      case 6:
        newScene = Level6(size: frame.size)
      case 7:
        newScene = Level7(size: frame.size)
      default:
        newScene = Level1(size: frame.size)
      }
      view?.presentScene(newScene, transition: .crossFade(withDuration: 0.5))
    }
  }
}
```

To me, this switch looks incredibly ugly and pointless, but I can't think of a way to avoid it. I was hoping someone here could help me out with this, I just can't think of a better alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could construct your Level's class name as a string `"Level\(name)"` first and then get the actual class you need by passing it's name to the function:

```
func classFromString(_ className: String) -> AnyClass! {
    let namespace = Bundle.main.infoDictionary!["CFBundleExecutable"] as! String
    let cls: AnyClass = NSClassFromString("\(namespace).\(className)")!
    return cls
}
```

Usage example:

```
let className = "Level1"
let levelInstance = (classFromString(className) as! GameScene).init(size: frame.size)
```

... but of course  the best advice would be to avoid such kind of architecture

Comment: @MysteryPancake it is a subject for another question, there are multiple ways to design game levels architecture. Like Initializing scene's properties in the constructor, passing index to it, or mapping level's indexes to appropriate GameScenes somewhere in struct or enum.
Since you said "it's a lot easier this way for what I'm doing, don't judge me" I gave you a hint for your particular case. If you find my answer useful, please accept it. Cheers =)

Answer (score -1):

You can do this instead:

```
    var newScene: GameScene!

    //Level1 is repeating on 0 and 1'st index

    let arrScene : [GameScene] = [Level1(size: frame.size),Level1(size: frame.size),Level2(size: frame.size),Level3(size: frame.size),Level4(size: frame.size),Level5(size: frame.size),Level6(size: frame.size),Level7(size: frame.size)]

    if Int(name)! <=7 && Int(name)! > 0{

    newScene  = arrScene[Int(name)!]

    }else{

    //Default level1 
    newScene  = arrScene[0]

    }
```